# re: windows xp like web app uses jquery and doesnt work

Tags: jquery

I happen to be messing with JQuery lately, and I decided to make something like win xp where you have windows that you can: minimize, close, and maximize. And when minimized the window should be marked in a taskbar as minimized.

My code: http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/xbaRJz
And snippet for those of you interested:

```js
$(function() {
  var window = ".window";
  var head = ".head";
  var close = ".close";
  var maximize = ".maximize";
  var minimize = ".minimize";
  var app = ".app";
  var w1 = $(".w1").clone();
 var w2 = $(".w2").clone();

  $(window).draggable({handle:head}).resizable();

  $(window).focus(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#000000",
      "z-index": "1"
    });
  });
  $(head).focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      "background-color": "#000000",
      "z-index": "1"
    });
  });
  $(window).blur(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#444444",
      "z-index": "0"
    });
  });
  
  $(close).click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".window").remove();
    alert("Closing window");
  });

  $(maximize).click(function() {
  if($(this).parents(".window").css("width") == "100vw" && $(this).parents(".window").css("height") == "100vh") {
      $(this).parents(".window").css({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "200px"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).parents(".window").css({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "100vw",
        "height": "100vh"
      });
    }
  });

  $(minimize).click(function() {
    var element = $(this).parents(".window")[0];
    $(this).parents(".window").css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    if(element == $(".w1")[0]) {
      $(".app1").css({
        "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
      });
    } else if(element == $(".w2")[0]) {
      $(".app2").css({
        "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
      });
    }
  });

  $(".app1").click(function() {
    if($(".w1").length) {
      if($(".w1").css("display") == "none") {
        $(".w1").css({
          "display": "block"
        });
        $(".app1").css({
          "background-color": "#ffffff"
        });
      } else {
        alert("app already exists");
      }
    } else {
      alert("making new app");
      $("body").append(w1);
      newapp();
    }
  });

  $(".app2").click(function() {
    if($(".w2").length) {
      if($(".w2").css("display") == "none") {
        $(".w2").css({
          "display": "block"
        });
        $(".app2").css({
          "background-color": "#ffffff"
        });
      } else {
        alert("app already exists");
      }
    } else {
      alert("making new app");
      $("body").append(w2);
      newapp();
    }
  });
  
  function newapp() {
   $(window).draggable({handle:head}).resizable();
 
   $(window).focus(function() {
     $(this).css({
       "background-color": "#000000",
       "z-index": "1"
     });
   });

    $(head).focus(function() {
     $(this).parent().css({
       "background-color": "#000000",
       "z-index": "1"
     });
   });

    $(window).blur(function() {
     $(this).css({
       "background-color": "#444444",
       "z-index": "0"
     });
   });
   
   $(close).click(function() {
     $(this).parents(".window").remove();
      alert("Closing window");
   });

    $(minimize).click(function() {
     var element = $(this).parents(".window")[0];
     $(this).parents(".window").css({
       "display": "none"
     });
     if(element == $(".w1")[0]) {
       $(".app1").css({
         "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
       });
     } else if(element == $(".w2")[0]) {
       $(".app2").css({
         "background-color": "#aaaaaa"
       });
     }
   });
    
    $(maximize).click(function() {
  if($(this).parents(".window").css("width") == "100vw" && $(this).parents(".window").css("height") == "100vh") {
       $(this).parents(".window").css({
         "top": "0",
         "left": "0",
         "width": "500px",
         "height": "200px"
       });
     } else {
       $(this).parents(".window").css({
         "top": "0",
         "left": "0",
         "width": "100vw",
         "height": "100vh"
       });
     }
   });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#taskbar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*#start_menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}*/
/*#menu {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 2em;
  display: none;
}*/

.app {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
}

.window {
  width: 500px;
  min-width: 275px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 125px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 2em);
  background-color: #444444;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.head {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.buttons {
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: .1em;
  top: -1.1em;
  background-color: #aa0000;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.maximize {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.4em;
  top: -1.1em;
  background-color: #dddd00;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minimize {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.6em;
  top: -1.1em;
  background-color: #0000dd;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="taskbar">
  <div id="start_menu"></div>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="app app1">W1</div>
    <div class="app app2">W2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="window w1">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="title">Window 1</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="close"></div>
      <div class="maximize"></div>
      <div class="minimize"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="window w2">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="title">Window 2</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="close"></div>
      <div class="maximize"></div>
      <div class="minimize"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But you see, I happen to find the following problems in my code:

- When clicked in a window, the window does not increment z-index
- I'm having a lot of trouble making a maximize button. The windows do maximize, but they don't unmaximize
- When dragging a window to the right, a scrollbar appears at the bottom, so you can scroll, as the browser window scroll by itself. This is a non wanted effect

The code happens to be so complicated for my brain, that I could not identify where exactly the problems are. What I do know, is that the problems are between line 42 and line 124 of the js column(codepen). As you can see it is a wide range.

Sorry I can't do any better, I just don't know where the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest not declaring a `window` variable. You will find that it will cause problems, being that `window` is the global object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maximize/Restore not working:**

Your maximize/restore didn't work because your if/else should be vice versa. The below code should work. Restored windows has got 500px & 200px size, so when you click maximize it should go to 100vw & 100vh isn't it?

```
$(maximize).click(function() {
        if($(this).parents(".window").css("width") == "500px" && $(this).parents(".window").css("height") == "200px") {
      $(this).parents(".window").css({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "100vw",
        "height": "100vh"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).parents(".window").css({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "200px"
      });
    }
  });
```

**Window focus problem:**

Div element doesn't need to get focus unless it contains any form elements like select, input or links etc. So by default focus will not get fired for div elements. So by that theory your jquery function for focus/blur will never get fired,

```
 $(window).focus(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#000000",
      "z-index": "1"
    });
  });
  $(head).focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      "background-color": "#000000",
      "z-index": "1"
    });
  });
  $(window).blur(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "#444444",
      "z-index": "0"
    });
  });
```

but there is a way to make it work, just add tabindex attribute to your div elements like below with any tabindex value which will make your div element receive focus.

```
<div class="window w1" tabindex="-1">
<div class="window w2" tabindex="-1">
```

**Dragging out to right is wrong:**

Your problem about dragging window to the right can be fixed with a small option with "draggable",

```
$(window).draggable({containment: "parent",handle:head}).resizable();
```

with *containment: "parent"*, your div element dragging is limited within the parent, will not go outside it and you will not see scrollbar anymore.

**Update #1:**

***For focus not working on head div element click:***
I think this is how draggable() jquery call is programmed which makes focus event suppressed for some reason. There were many bugs reported to bugs.jqueryui.com about this for different elements. Back to your problem on window focus, I believe after above solution your issue is only while clicking on title of the window. Because I have checked clicking on body of the window and it works fine. For your title we can do a workaround by not using draggable() instead using a manual drag code as explained below,

Considering your window part of html like below,

```
<div class="window w1" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="title">Window 1</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="close"></div>
      <div class="maximize"></div>
      <div class="minimize"></div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use onmouseup, onmousedown, onmousemove events to do a manual move of the window, a typical programmatic way of doing it in whatever programming we always do.

```
//  $(window).draggable({containment: "parent",handle:head}).resizable();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // the below $mywindow is important as that starts and stops the drag operation
        var $mywindow = null;
        var xdiff=0;
        var ydiff=0;
        $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {

            if ($mywindow) {   // see if drag started on our element
                if($mywindow.attr("class")==="head"){  // see if whether it is actually our head element for dragging
                    // and by the way we have to drag our whole window not just head, so .parent()
                    $mywindow.parent().offset({
                        top: e.pageY - ydiff,
                        left: e.pageX - xdiff
                    });                 
                }
            }
        });
        $(document.body).on("mousedown", "div", function (e) {
            // level up to head as we are clicking on title element
            $mywindow = $(e.target).parent(); 
              xdiff=e.pageX -$mywindow.offset().left;
              ydiff=e.pageY - $mywindow.offset().top;
        });

        $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
            xdiff=0;
            ydiff=0;

            // make it null so that the above if($mywindow) will fail on mousemove
            $mywindow = null;
        });
    });
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

By they way, consider not using $(window) for your window object as that is also referring to global window object, instead try using something like $(hwnd) ;) I am basically a VC++ guy. No problem as of now, but the problem and confusion will be when you try to use the actual $(window) object. for eg: to check the boundary of the window to limit your dragging etc. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I quite appreciate that you told me exactly what I was doing right and explained it to me.

Comment: tab index does not work, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp sorry to notify you so late, I had a rough time trying to make it work

Comment: The problem is with draggable() call, please check the answer for an alternative solution for that. Note that, I am leaving it to you to put some checks to limit window dragging out of screen. btw, this drag will not give you any scrollbar anyways.